# Set different subtitles colors/brightness for sdr/hdr content respectively with mpc-be?

Tags: video, media-player-classic

I use mpc-be to play videos. One annoying issue is that the subtitle's colors/brightness I set for SDR content become too bright when I change to play HDR content. So I have to change subtitle's colors/brightness back and forth when I switch between SDR and HDR content.

Is there any way to set different subtitles colors/brightness for sdr/hdr content respectively with mpc-be or any workaround?

Comment: download Process Monitor from Microsoft and run it ... change subtitle color ... determine if the mpc-be changes the windows registry ... examine the registry keys that are changed ... it may point to a solution ... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon ... if the registry keys are changed, then maybe you could have a shortcut on the desktop to change the settings with a click